# Return values from array interatively from a function with a setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am developing a front-end application that loop through an array comprised of acceleration values and timestamps. These values will be used in animating a div (a moving vehicle).

To prevent parsing and loading the entire JSON file at once, I added a `setTimeout` to loop through the strings every second. To make use of this incoming data, I then need to access these values in another function which will be fed to css keyframes as a dynamic values. The ultimate goal is to animate the div according to the incoming data.

I have an issue in accessing the value from the json string outside of the myLoop() function.

I have the following json string:

```
data=[
    {
        "time": 0,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 86400,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 172800,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 259200,
        "accX": 0.11,
        "accZ": 0.11
    },
    {
        "time": 345600,
        "accX": 0.35,
        "accZ": 0.11
    }
]
```

Here is my function that loop through the json string every second:

```
    var i = 0; 
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    let acceleration_x,acceleration_z,timestamp;
    
    function myLoop() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {   
        acceleration_x = data[i].accX;
        acceleration_z = data[i].accZ;
        timestamp      = data[i].time;
        i++;                    
        if (i < data.length) {          
          myLoop();  
        } 
        console.log(acceleration_x, acceleration_z,timestamp)                
      }, 1000)
      return {
        acceleration_x,
        acceleration_z,
        timestamp
    };
    }
```

I need to access acceleration_x, acceleration_z and timestamp in this function:

```
function play(animation) {
  myLoop(); // Here i need to access the acceleration and timer value and feed it to the keyframes
    $('.track').resetKeyframe(function() {
        switch (animation) {
            case 'normal':

            $('.track').playKeyframe({
                name: 'carMove',
                duration: "13s",
                timingFunction: 'linear',
                iterationCount: 'infinite',
                direction: 'normal',
                fillMode: 'forwards'
              });

              $('.car').playKeyframe({
                name: 'shake',
                duration: "3s",
                timingFunction: 'linear',
                iterationCount: 'infinite',
                direction: 'normal',
                fillMode: 'forwards'
              });
            break;
        }
        
    })
}
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `data` is not JSON. The only spot with actual JSON is the return value of `JSON.stringify()` in the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` construct.

Comment: I got what you mean. after initialising the path of my json like <script src="./data/accXaccZCOMBINEDMOTIONS.json"></script> I stringify and parse so I can access each individual value. But this is not my issue here, printing the data using console.log(data[i].time) inside myLoop() is fine, my problem is that I need to access these values outside myLoop() function and access them in function play(animation) {...}

Comment: You're not saving any time "parsing and loading the entire JSON file at once". If you load the first as described (via a `script` element's `src` attribute), it's already been parsed and loaded; you don't need to stringify and parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you could not get the data outside of `myLoop()` is that `setTimeout()` runs asynchronously.  It means that the `setTimeout()` code is enqueued in the task list and JS engine returns immediately to execute the next line.  The enqueued task is invoked after 1 second by the event loop.  So the `return` statement is actually executed before the enqueued task is invoked which results in returning no informations.

In order to obtain the result from the asynchronous task, you have to create `Promise` and pass the result to `resolve()` function.  I put that code into `tick()` function.  Just call the `tick()` wherever you need the data to feed to the keyframe.  I left the comments for you where you should put the code for feeding keyframe.

```
    async function myLoop (data) {
      function tick (obj) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve({
            acceleration_x: obj.accX,
            acceleration_z: obj.accZ,
            timestamp: obj.time
          }), 1000)
        });
      }
      /* -------------------------------------
         feed the data to your keyframe here
         ------------------------------------- */
      for (let ele of data) {
        const keyframe = await tick(ele);
        console.log(keyframe);
      };
    }

    function play () {
      myLoop(data);
    }

    play();
```

Below is the complete code to run and test.  If you have further requirement, I can update the answer for you.  Just leave comments.

```js
const data = [{
    "time": 0,
    "accX": 0.11,
    "accZ": 0.11
  },
  {
    "time": 86400,
    "accX": 0.11,
    "accZ": 0.11
  },
  {
    "time": 172800,
    "accX": 0.11,
    "accZ": 0.11
  },
  {
    "time": 259200,
    "accX": 0.11,
    "accZ": 0.11
  },
  {
    "time": 345600,
    "accX": 0.35,
    "accZ": 0.11
  }
];


async function myLoop (data) {
  function tick (obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve({
        acceleration_x: obj.accX,
        acceleration_z: obj.accZ,
        timestamp: obj.time
      }), 1000)
    });
  }
  /* -------------------------------------
     feed the data to your keyframe here
     ------------------------------------- */
  for (let ele of data) {
    const keyframe = await tick(ele);
    console.log(keyframe);
  };
}

function play () {
  myLoop(data);
}

play();
```

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem

Comment: That's good to hear.  Happy coding!